# I want to port a module from Python 2 to 3, how do I run tests?

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, python-3.x, testing

I've been writing in Python 3 for a while, I came across this library that I really need:
https://github.com/Yelp/python-gearman

but I want to try to port it to Python 3. But I don't know how one runs the tests in a Python module. I tried python -m unittest discover but it didn't discover any tests. And once I actually do change something to Python 3, how would I test it? Is the testing mechanism the same in Python 3 as in 2?

Comment: You should check to see if any of those forks have a Python 3 version.

Comment: make sure you read ["Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3" by Brett Cannon](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First figure out how to run the tests in 2.7, assuming that the test directory is installed along with the gearman directory.  (It should be if you have git and clone the github repository, but I have not used git, just hg.)  In the test/ directory, add and run a shell/console script like the following.  (You did not specify OS.)

```
python -m admin_client_tests
python -m client_tests
python -m protocol_tests
python -m worker_tests
```

where `python` invokes 2.7 on your system.  Each of these modules imports _core_testing.py, which should not be run directly.  There should be a way to run all tests at once, and it should be documented, but the authors may not expect users to run them.  Anyway, run 2to3 to produce a new package directory, look at messages, change `python` to run 3.x, and test.  Process difficulty may be anything from 'no-brainer' to 'give-it-up'.  (I did one conversion that was about a 1 or 2 on 0 to 10 difficulty scale.)  If successful, asks authors if they want to either make code 2 and 3 compatible or have a separate 3.x version.

Comment: use the full module name i.e., it should be `python -m tests.client_tests`

Comment: Nowhere in my comment I said anything about `test` vs. `tests`. Do you understand why one should not run scripts from **inside** Python packages?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are correct that the second package directory in the repository is `tests`, not `test`; I edited my answer.  In any case, a cloned repository is not, by default, included in sys.path, but the 'current working directory' is, as `''`.  I specified 'In the `tests` directory, ... run ...` and wrote the script to match.  If `tests.` is prefixed, one would have to be in and run from `python-gearman` directory.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No, you just used the correct name and I noticed the difference.  Sorry I you object to the credit ;-).  No, I do not understand what you are getting at.

Comment: `tests` is a Python package (look at `__init__.py`). Without the `tests` prefix, you are running the modules from **inside** the package and therefore the same module can be accessible under different names (it may create surprising failures due to an unshared  global state). See [Traps for the unaware](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#traps-for-the-unwary). Also, running from the root adds it to `sys.path`

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the pattern explicitly (the default: `test*.py` doesn't work in this case):

```
$ python -m unittest discover -p \*_tests.py
.............................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 61 tests in 0.040s

OK
```

To run individual test files:

```
$ python -m tests.client_tests
```